# Setting a flag in a for loop to be used in the callback function of a function called within the same loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I am trying to identify the last callback function call within the following loop. Currently, the loop is executing faster than the inner function, and by the flag is being set to true before the last callback. What I need is for the flag to be set to true only during the last callback. How do I modify the following code:

```
// global variable flag
var flag = false;
var files = [..]; // some array of files
var count = files.length;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  flag = count - i == 1; // Sets true when last item is processed in the files array 
  request = some-api.get(file.id);
  request.execute(callback.bind(this));
}

function callback(data){
  if(flag){
    // Do something with data
    data.use();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `.execute()` asynchronous?  If so, you should pass the flag to the callback, not try to use it in a global variable.  `.bind()` will allow you to pass additional arguments beyond what `.execute()` would normally send to it.

Comment: `.execute()` is asynchronous. That is whats causing the issue. It is not my code but an API I am using. With that, I don't think I can pass the flag to the callback method. Any other ideas?

Comment: `.bind()` can solve this issue for you.  I've illustrated how in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.execute()` is asynchronous, you cannot use a global flag to communicate with the callback because you have no idea when the callback will be called and there's no way to give one global flag value to one invocation of the callback and a different one to another invocation of the callback.

Instead, you can pass the flag to the callback using a capability of `.bind()` to add arguments to the function.  It could be done like this:

```
// global variable flag
var files = [..]; // some array of files

for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var flag = (i >= files.length - 1); // true when we are on last item
  some-api.get(files[i].id).execute(callback.bind(this, flag));
}

function callback(flag, data){
  if(flag){
    // Do something with data
    data.use();
  }
}
```

Arguments you pass to `.bind()` after the `this` pointer will be prepended to the arguments that would otherwise be sent to the callback.  So essentially `.execute()` will call your the `.bind()` wrapper with one single argument and then the `.bind()` wrapper will insert your argument in before calling the actual callback.  As long as you declare your callback arguments knowing how this works, you will get exactly what you want.